# data is not parsing inside the json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to fetch data through js function using pdo and bootstrap modal but my problem is data is not coming properly inside json through php function. details.php is not getting data properly and i am getting uncaught syntax error in getEventDetails function in json parsing.
here is my code

here I'am fetching data and performing update function

```
<html>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <form method="POST">
        <tr>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>Event Date</th>
            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            include '../class.php';

            $object = new crud();
            $users = $object->readEvent();

            if (count($users) > 0) 
            {
                $number = 1;
                foreach ($users as $user) 
                {
                echo '<tr>

                <td>'.$user['Event_Name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$user['Event_Date'].'</td>
                <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="GetEventDetails('.$user['Event_ID'].')" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onClick="DeleteEvent('.$user['Event_ID'].')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
                </tr>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </form>
</table>

<!-- Modal-Update Event List-->
<div class="modal fade" id="update_event_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="update_event_name">Event Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="update_event_name" class="form-control"/>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="update_event_date" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Date and time</label>
                <input type="text" id="update_event_date" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updateEvent()" >Save Changes</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="hidden_event_id">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

GetEventDetail function

```
function GetEventDetails(id) 
{
    // Add User ID to the hidden field for furture usage
    $("#hidden_event_id").val(id);
    $.post("ajax/details.php",
    {
        id: id
    },
    function (data, status) 
    {
        // PARSE json data
        var user = JSON.parse(data);
        // Assing existing values to the modal popup fields
        $("#update_event_name").val(user.event_name);
        $("#update_event_date").val(user.event_date);

    }
    );
    // Open modal popup
    $("#update_event_modal").modal("show");
}
```

after this it goes to details.php, code for details.php

```
<?php
include '../class.php';
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['id']) != "")
{
    $user_id = $_POST['id'];
    //echo $id;

    $object = new crud();
    $object->EventDetails($user_id);
}
else
{
    echo 0;
}
```

?>

and it goes to php function.

```
public function EventDetails($user_id)
    {
        $query = $this->DB_conn->prepare("SELECT Event_Name, Event_Date FROM My_Event WHERE Event_ID = :id");
        $query->bindParam("id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        return json_encode($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }
```

Update event fucntion

```
   function updateEvent() 
   {
      // get values
      var update_event_name = $("#update_event_name").val();
      var update_event_date = $("#update_event_date").val();
      //update_category_name = update_category_name.trim();

        // get hidden field value
        var id = $("#hidden_event_id").val();

        // Update the details by requesting to the server using ajax
         $.post("ajax/updatedata.php", 
         {
            id: id,
            update_event_name: update_event_name,
            update_event_date: update_event_date
         },
         function (data, status) 
         {

            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            $("#update_event_modal").modal("hide");

            // read records again
            readEvent();

            // clear fields from the popup
            $("#update_event_name").val("");
            $("#update_event_date").val("");
         }
       );
  }
```

updatedata.php

```
<?php
include("../class.php");
   if (isset($_POST['update_event_name']) && isset($_POST['update_event_date']) && isset($_POST['id'])) 
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $update_event_name = $_POST['update_event_name'];
        $update_wedding_date = $_POST['update_event_date'];

        $object = new crud();
        $object->UpdateEvent($update_event_name, $update_wedding_date, $id);
    }
    else
    {
       echo 0;
    }
  ?>

   public function UpdateEvent($update_event_name, $update_wedding_date,$id)
   {
        $query = $this->DB_conn->prepare("UPDATE My_event SET Event_Name = :update_event_name, Event_Date = :update_wedding_date WHERE Event_ID = :id");
        $query->bindParam("update_event_name", $update_event_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("update_wedding_date", $update_wedding_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `updateEvent()` is javascript but you are trying to call it from a PHP script. It would be useful to know what errors you are getting

Comment: no I'm using both the functions separately one is for JS and another for php.

Comment: But I dont see an UpdateEvent in your crud class

Comment: @RiggsFolly now check please, but issue is with eventdetail function data is not coming there properly.

Comment: [How to create an MCVE for a PDO related problem.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You don't receive the data, because you have never actually outputted that to the client. So, in your `details.php`:

```
echo $object->EventDetails($user_id);
```

and similarly, in the `updatedata.php`:

```
echo $object->UpdateEvent($update_event_name, $update_wedding_date, $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, problem was with json parse so i added litillt code and now it's working fine.

```
function GetEventDetails(id) 
{

    // Add User ID to the hidden field for furture usage
    $("#hidden_event_id").val(id);
    $.post("ajax/details.php",
    {
        id: id
    },
    function (data, status) 
    {
        var data_name = 0;
        var data_date = 0;

        // PARSE json data
        var user = JSON.parse(data);
        $(user).each(function(i,val)
        {
            $.each(val,function(k,v)
            {
              console.log(k+" : "+ v);     
              if(k == "Event_Name")
              {
                 data_name = v;
              }
              else if(k == "Event_Date")
              {
                 data_value = v;
              } 
        });
        });

        $("#update_event_name").val(data_name);
        $("#update_event_date").val(data_value);
    }
    );

    // Open modal popup
    $("#update_event_modal").modal("show");
 }
```